# lseek SEEK_END doesn't get last character

Tags: c, lseek

FIXED (SEE FINAL EDIT)

I am trying to get the last character of a file using lseek and read. The file I'm opening is this (no '\n' at the end):

```
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

I want the output to be 'd'. For some reason, doing lseek(file, -1, SEEK_END) does not seem to work. However, adding a redundant lseek(file, position, SEEK_SET) after it works. My code:

```
int file;
char c;
int position;

/*************** Attempt 1 (does not work) ***************/

file = open("test", O_RDONLY);
position = lseek(file, -1, SEEK_END);
printf("lseek returns %i\n", position);
printf("read returns %i\n", read(file, &c, 1));
printf("last character is \"%c\"\n\n", c);
close(file);

/********* Attempt 2 (seems redundant but works) *********/

file = open("test", O_RDONLY);
position = lseek(file, -1, SEEK_END);
printf("lseek returns %i\n", position);

/* ADDED LINES */
position = lseek(file, position, SEEK_SET);
printf("lseek returns %i\n", position);

printf("read returns %i\n", read(file, &c, 1));
printf("last character is \"%c\"\n\n", c);
close(file);
```

Gives an output:

```
lseek returns 42
read returns 0
last character is ""

lseek returns 42
lseek returns 42
read returns 1
last character is "g"
```

Does anyone know what's happening?

---

Edit: I've tried lseek(file, 0, SEEK_CUR) in place of lseek(file, position, 0) and it does not work, although it still returns 42.

Edit 2: Removed magic numbers.

---

Final edit: Fixed by adding #include <unistd.h>

Comment: same goes for open!

Comment: Fixed the magic numbers and/or the issue?

Comment: Sorry, fixed the magic numbers. Deleting previous comment to avoid confusion.

Comment: works here as expected; what is your environment (e.g. filesystem)? Do you see the syscalls with '`strace`?

Comment: one that comes to mind if if you didnt include correct headers...

Comment: Adding <unistd.h> fixed the problem. Thank you for all of the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved issue by adding

```
#include <unistd.h>
```

Comment: This solution indicates that you didn't have a proper declaration of the `lseek` function. If the compiler didn't warn you about it, then consider enabling more warnings when building. I recommend at least the `-Wall` flag. Personally I use at least `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've added them and realized another import that I needed for an assignment.